# Network volume sent from sql instance to specific machine

Tags: sql-server

SQL2017/Windows2016 instance serving many clients and applications. what are the options to capture network volume sent to specific machine/IP during specific time frames?

There is application machine running the batch process on a schedule and I need to know how many MBs being sent from SQL instance to that specific machine during the processing of that batch process.

From Perfmon and DMV, I have total bytes sent and also total IO of the databases involved in processing that batch, but still, need how many MBs of that volume is being sent back through the network to that application machine.

Thanks!

Comment: Is measuring things at the *client* machine an option? As that'd be a lot simpler than filtering out the data on the server. Otherwise I'm pretty sure you're looking at a packet trace and some post-processing, like `netsh trace` or Wireshark.

Comment: thank you. Unfortunately - I can't access that app machine and prefer not to  as it is a very busy app machine running all kinds of SSIS pkgs and other app stuff. But, I have full access on the sql instance machine.